# Overlaying divs for emailer

Tags: html, css, gmail, overlay

I'm trying to design an emailer that will be responsive and not go to trash when opened in an email client. So this puts a bunch of restrictions:

- No background size/positioning
- No negative margins
- No position attribute
- No display attribute
- Prefer not to use Tables

A more complete list of restrictions on Gmail can be found here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Now I have to work with images that aren't going to be to size of the div and need to be scaled up or down to cover the background. I also need to place a dark overlay so that white text can be visible even on a white background. I tried to get close but haven't found a way to get the background images to cover the entire div. This was my latest attempt:

```
#background{
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/320x400); 
    background-position:50% 50%; /*not allowed*/
    background-size:cover; /*Not allowed*/
    margin:5px; 
    max-height:400px;
    max-width:320px; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    z-index:0; 
    float:left; 
}
#overlay{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.35); 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
    max-height:400px;
}
#cat{
    padding:10px; 
    font-size:10px; 
    letter-spacing:.5em; 
    text-transform:uppercase; color:white;
}
#title{
    font-size: 20px; 
    max-width: 243px; 
    padding:10px 200px 340px 10px; 
    vertical-align:bottom; 
    letter-spacing:0; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    word-wrap:break-word; 
    overflow: auto; /*hidden isn't allowed!?*/
    font-family: &quot;Oswald&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; 
    color:white;
}


<body>
    <div style="display:flex;">
        <div id="background">       
            <div id="overlay">
                <div id="cat">category</div>
                <div id="title">title</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r0zk02eh/

I've more or less resigned to the fact it's not possible but would love to be proved wrong.